# QNX momentics linked source files not compiling

Tags: qnx, qnx-neutrino, momentics

I am creating a QNX port for a Linux application. As a test, i copied all source code and header files into /src/ directrory and built the code. the binary was created, and I was able to execute on target VM. but now I have to create the momentics project inside the project folder, without altering or creating duplicate copies of existing source files. 
I found that I can use linked resources. So I followed steps provided [here](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.ide.userguide%2Ftopic%2Fcvs_IMPORT_.html) and could add the file to project.

[image: adding linked resource]

[image: after adding]

but when I compile the project, it is not taking the linked files.

[image: copiling]

As one can clearly see the process is directly going to linking stage.

but if I add a new cpp file without linking, only that particular file is getting compiled, not the linked file.
[image: only the new main.cpp is getting compiled]
only the new main.cpp is getting compiled.

Can anyone help me to get this project built, only using linked resources?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use IDE for compiling my writing a Makefile and importing it to IDE.